# Why updates overwrites Vim that built from source?

Tags: debian, vim

I build Vim from source, and install it with `checkinstall`. Soon after *Software&Updates* warned there is an update for Vim. But after the installation, Vim path is altered and another build take its place and my build from source disappeared. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: The "update" installed a new copy of vim.  If you want to have a different one, install it in a different directory.  If you don't want it to be overwritten, tell the packaging system to hold/pin the package.

Answer (score 2):

I build Vim, so it is installed in a custom directory. I call configure like this:

```
configure --prefix=/usr/local/mybuild/vim --mandir=/usr/local/mybuild/vim/share/man --without-local-dir ...
```

then I do

```
make
make test
make install
```

the executable is then `/usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim`.

To update the alternative links I executed the following. This is only needed once, not after every `make install`.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/eview eview /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/evim evim /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ex ex /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gview gview /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gvim gvim /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gvimdiff gvimdiff /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rgview rgview /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rgvim rgvim /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rview rview /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rvim rvim /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/view view /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vim vim /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vimdiff vimdiff /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim 1200
```

I have chosen a high priority (1200), so that system-installs will not replace the links.

Now Vim is `/usr/bin/vim`, which is a link to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which in turn is a link to `/usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim`. So calling `vim` starts my private build of Vim.

To see how the alternatives for vim are configured, you can run `update-alternatives --display vim`. On my machine it produces the following output:

```
$ update-alternatives --display vim
vim - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim
  link currently points to /usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim
  link vim is /usr/bin/vim
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
/usr/bin/vim.gtk3 - priority 50
/usr/local/mybuild/vim/bin/vim - priority 1200
```

Answer (score 1):

One of two things happened:

1. You used the same package name as your distro did, but your distro update package has a higher version. So the package manager happily "upgraded" your custom build to your distro's version. Solution: remove your distro's package & use a different name for your local package (such as `local-vim`). If you must use the same name (e.g., due to dependencies), then use a higher version. For example, on Debian, you could add an epoch.
2. You installed your vim-from-source into `/usr`, and the files from your distro's package use the same names. Thus your files were overwritten. Less likely, as a lot of package managers would yell pretty loudly about this... Solution is to use a different path (like `/opt` or `/usr/local`) or not install your distro package.